# postscript file

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am printing an 8x8 book with 40 pages, and when I save my file as a postscript file under the print setting dialog box, when I view my file in preview it only counts up to 20 pages, not 40.

What happened to the rest of my pages?

Comment: Is there a particularly good reason not to export to PDF? PostScript is quickly becoming obsolete in most workflows.

Comment: yes, I had my file as a PDF before and when I took my PDF to be printed, I needed it to be saddle stitch bound, and the pages would not print correctly nor could I get to the option to change the binding setting on the printer I was at ( a graphic design lab on my college campus)

Comment: therefore I was told that my file needed to be a postscript file in order for my pages to print correctly

Answer (score 1):

You might have printed/exported as spreads which would be 2 pages per sheet. Check your Print Settings. I think there is a checkbox in the Print dialog as well.

Good Luck.

Comment: I should have the spreads turned off then?

Comment: No you have to have Printer Spreads for it to print correctly. The way I did this last time was to generate the Postscript files and then convert those to PDF using Acrobat Distiller. Go to File>Print Booklet choose 2-Up Saddle Stitch. Print to File to generate the file you need. It's tricky at first.